# Is a room-temperature & pressure single-photon sensor theoretically possible?

Tags: photons, quantum-information, superconductivity, photonics

In the realm of photonic quantum computing, single-photon sensors are required for determining the outputs of each chip. Unlike most forms of QC, photonic chips themselves may be run at room temperature and pressure.

Readout from the photonic chips, on the other hand, is generally done with superconducting single-photon detectors which require a cold vacuum. I am wondering if there exists a way of detecting these photons semi-reliably in a RT&P environment, along with what the error levels would most likely be.

Thank you so much - Jackson